# Dynamically call method name from string value using proxy class for web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created proxy web service in my project. I want to call method name from parameter as a string and I need to get response from these methods, but it returns as a string only. So please anyone help me.

Here I need to pass MethodName.

for eg:

```
string response = mut.MethodName(RequestData);

[WebMethod]
public string CALLPROXY(string MethodName, string RequestData)
{

    WebReference.IMPSMethods mut = new WebReference.IMPSMethods();
    mut.Url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.asmx?wsdl";
    mut.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    //string response = mut.LOGIN(RequestData);
    string response = mut + "." + MethodName + "(" + RequestData + ")";
    return response;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string response = typeof(WebReference.IMPSMethods)
                     .GetMethod(MethodName)
                     .Invoke(mut, new object[] { RequestData })
```

If your class `IMPSMethods` has overloads, you will  need to use the overloaded .GetMethod() call to narrow it down (looking for particular parameter types, etc).